# Is this Fischer Projection of (3R, 4S)-3-ethyl-3,4-dimethyl-1-hexene wrong?

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, stereochemistry, erratum

(3R, 4S)-3-ethyl-3,4-dimethyl-1-hexene

Draw the Fischer Projection of the compound above.

Here is the answer:

[image: Answer]

Is there a mistake at the upper stereocenter? I think so.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a mistake at the upper stereocenter?

Yes you are thinking correct, the R configuration will be the diastereomeric pair of this compund, the second chiral carbon is in correct configuration. Don't you want to ask why?

[image]

Comment: How can it be a diastereomer when there is a double bond in the group at the top? I thought diastereomers needed to have a mirror plane on the bond between chiral centers.

Comment: @LDC3 see the figure, they're not enantiomers, nor homomers, not structural isomers and so on, and the one thing left is diastereomers